# ServiceStack OrmLite - Handle Auto increment column default seed

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

How can i set a auto increment column seed from 1 to 100??
in sql server can do this use

```
 ADD Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1000,1)
```

but in ormlite autoincrement attribute seems like **always start with 1.**

tried also

```
 db.AlterTable<MSchool>("command") // DROP ID AND ADD AUTO INCREMENT COLUMN
```

it works, if Id doesn't related to any table.

can i set a column autoincrement with  default seed and increment?

```
[AutoIncrement(1000,1)]
public int Id {get;set;}
```

**UPDATE**

Resolved, but not good

```
public class School
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

//then create table
db.CreateTable<School>();

//then update seed
db.ExecuteSql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('School',reseed,1000)");
```

OR

```
[PostCreateTable("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('School',reseed,1000)")]
public class School : BaseModel
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

Is there no easier way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I don't believe this behavior belongs inside source code and would just modify the database out-of-band.

But if I were to add it in source code I'd do something like:

```
if (db.CreateTableIfNotExists<School>())
{
    db.ExecuteSql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('School',reseed,1000)");
}
```

So it only resets the seed if the table doesn't exist.

Another option is attach it to the model at runtime so it's decoupled from the class definition with:

```
typeof(School)
    .AddAttributes(new PostCreateTableAttribute(
        "DBCC CHECKIDENT ('School',reseed,1000)"));
```

Comment: you are right, it's not belongs inside source code. just to test feature before i purchase, thanks your response.